# Need Macro/Function/formula to Replace the Values of one Excel Sheet if both Email(Column) value matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have 2 Excel 2007 Worksheets.

Excel Worksheet 1 : (as below ) 3 Columns are important in Sheet 1

```
userid   name   email

100      sam    sam@sam.com
200      pete   pete@pete.com
300      Bum    Bum@Bum.com 
400      Harry  Harry@Harry.com
```

Worksheet 2 : (as below) ( user_id column is empty for all )

```
userid   name   email

         sam    sam@sam.com
         Harry  Harry@Harry.com 
         pete   pete@pete.com
         Bum    Bum@Bum.com
```

I need a function/forumla with a macro where i can fill the values for userid in sheet 2
where the sheet2 email = sheet1 email

which will result as following in worksheet 2

```
userid   name   email

100      sam    sam@sam.com
400      Harry  Harry@Harry.com 
200      pete   pete@pete.com
300      Bum    Bum@Bum.com
```

I know SQL but the query takes a long long time on MySQL DB to get the result...
Anyways below is the SQL query i was using in the DB.

```
UPDATE  `j_A` 
SET user_id =   ( SELECT j_B.id
FROM j_B
WHERE j_B.email =  j_A.email)
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT j_B.id
    FROM j_B
    WHERE j_B.email =  j_A.email);
```

Need Macro/Function/formula to Replace the Values of one Excel Sheet if both Email(Column) value matches,, if anyone cud help me regarding this creating Macro/Formula/functin etc...since 
dont have much knowldge of creating formulae in Excel Macros..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your example, try:

```
Sub HTH
    With Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = Replace("=LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!C$2:C$x=C2)/(Sheet1!B$2:B$x=B2),Sheet1!A$2:A$x)", _
            "x", (Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1))
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

It will probably be more efficient to update the SQL query.

To open the VBA editor press Alt-F11.

Here is a screenshot of the code in the VBA editor with the code sample, click the green play button to run the code:

[image]

Based on the additional info you may want to try this alternative procdure:

```
Sub HTH2()
    Dim vSource As Variant
    Dim vOutput As Variant
    Dim sKey As String

    vSource = Sheet1.UsedRange.Resize(, 3).Value
    vOutput = Sheet2.UsedRange.Resize(, 3).Value

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For lloop = 1 To UBound(vSource, 1)
            .Add vSource(lloop, 2) & ":" & vSource(lloop, 3), vSource(lloop, 1)
        Next lloop

        For lloop = 1 To UBound(vOutput, 1)
            sKey = vOutput(lloop, 2) & ":" & vOutput(lloop, 3)
            If .exists(sKey) Then
                vOutput(lloop, 1) = .Item(sKey)
            Else
                vOutput(lloop, 1) = ""
            End If
        Next lloop
    End With

    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vOutput, 1), 1).Value = vOutput

End Sub
```

Comment: Update the SQL query? I somehow got queries stacking up in the MySQL so twice i had to restart the MySQL to clear the queries..Is there something wrong with the query? Ok so this code you supplied above is what Macro or VBA i need to insert inside a MAcro? or a formula?  Thanks

Comment: Place the code above in a module in the VBA editor and run it.  IF you just want to use a formula then place the following formula in cell A2: =LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet1!C$2:C$5=C2)/(Sheet1!B$2:B$5=B2),Sheet1!A$2:A$5)

Comment: Its moduleis working but i have about more than 10,00,00 records so...its just taking time to know if the value have changed...will wait till the function module has completed the job.

Comment: If that procedure takes too long too complete I will need to give you another solution based on arrays and the dictionary object.

Comment: Or perhaps i can break downthe records into smaller chunks and try it..? But it works i saw the value changed perfectly.

Comment: Yes if that works for you go for it.  Alternatively you can try the second piece of code I posted.  As you are new at stackoverflow,  if an answer solves your question then please remember to mark the solution as solved by clicking the big green tick.

Comment: ok th results from the first function is that i got #N/A  for all value for the userid in sheet 2.. But i tried it first on a small sample of 1,200 records it worked perfectly but when i tried on the actually records...it took about 35-40 minutes to complete and i got #N/A  for all userids in the sheet2...// Second Script you provided when i save it and run in inside the sheet ( i cannot..there is no run)..So then i tried playing/running it from the VB editor ...it runs but give some error.run time error 457
the key is already associated with an element of this collection

Comment: The code is setup for the exact layout as per your example, if your actual data is not in the same layout then the code will fail.  Regarding the second error, this means you have duplicate entries of name and email.

Comment: Hello Reafidy...Today its strange but nothing is working today? Why...What am i doing wrong,. please see this link http://youtu.be/l_dQqham6ns

Comment: You are trying to run the macros from the wrong book.  You are using Book3 however you are running the macros in another book called Book3 (autosaved).